# Change text of a label when a JButton is clicked java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

I'm try to change the text on a JLabel when the Jbutton is clicked but i can't figure it out why it turns the text into empty when i clicked the button. I'm trying to retrieve the data from the database.

heres my label

```
labelDisplay = new JLabel[7];

for(int z = 0; z<7; z++){
    labelDisplay[z] = new JLabel("d");
    labelDisplay[z].setForeground(new Color(230,230,230));
    if( z%2==0)
        labelDisplay[z].setBounds(130,65,160,25);
    else
        labelDisplay[z].setBounds(130,30,160,25);
}
```

I'm sure that my class for retrieving date is working i test it out.
heres my actionListener:

```
    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getSource() == extendB)
                {
                    ExtensionForm extend = new ExtensionForm();
                    extend.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()== searchB)
                {
                    //get text from the textField
                    String guest = guestIDTF.getText();
                    //parse the string to integer for retrieving of date
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(guest);
                    GuestsInfo guestInfo = new GuestsInfo(id);
                    Room roomInfo = new Room(id);
                    searchB.setText(""+id);
                    System.out.println(""+guestInfo.getFirstName());
                    labelDisplay[1].setText(""+id);
                    String labels[] = {guestInfo.getFirstName()+" "+guestInfo.getLastName(),
                            ""+roomInfo.getRoomNo(),roomInfo.getRoomType(),guestInfo.getTime(),"11:00",
                            ""+guestInfo.getDeposit(),"30"};
                    labels = new String[7];
                    for(int z = 0; z<labels.length; z++){
                        labelDisplay[z].setText(labels[z]);
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

I did put an initial value for the label text, as you can see from my code it's letter "d" but when i clicked the button it turns to empty.The accessor methods there are really working that why i suspect that the error is from my actionListener. Please help me guys

I edit the constructor it should be id not 1.

Heres the code for the actionListener for the button

```
ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
searchB = new JButton("search");
searchB.setBounds(190,30,75,25);
searchB.addActionListener(bh);
```

Comment: Did you check that your methods in your labels[] array actually return some text?

Comment: remove the line   labels = new String[7];   and it should probably work

Comment: @rempelos it work, but can you tell me why i shouldn't initialize the string like that? i though if i didn't put that line i would get a null pointer exception, explain me a bit your answer just want to know :)

Comment: @user1708134 It is perfectly valid to do so. What you had there was an initializer list. The compiler can infer the size of the array and allocate memory for it at runtime. 
However, when you set labels to new String[7], you created a new memory to overwrite the previous array.

Comment: First you put strings in your array and then you empty it by using the new keyword. By the way you should accept @LewsTherin's answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 labelDisplay[1].setText(""+id);

 String labels[] = {guestInfo.getFirstName()+" "+guestInfo.getLastName(),
      ""+roomInfo.getRoomNo(),roomInfo.getRoomType(), guestInfo.getTime(),
      "11:00", ""+guestInfo.getDeposit(),"30"};

 labels = new String[7];

 for(int z = 0; z<labels.length; z++){
      labelDisplay[z].setText(labels[z]);
 }
```

You never set your labels to something valid. Remove `labels = new String[7];`

Should have checked the code well sorry!

Comment: "using instanceof" java said extendB/searchB can't resolve to a type

Comment: That's because searchB isn't a class.. is searchB a class? What is searchB?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I should learn the virtue of patience :) In my arrogance I mislead :(

Comment: @user1708134: please check out Lews edit to his answer since it looks like it contains your solution.

Comment: it's ok sir, i just want to clarify should i put a reference variable for each getter? isn't the labels array a valid string?